# Combine dataframe within the list to form a single dataframe using pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, for-loop, iteration

Let say I have a list `df_list` with 3 single column pandas dataframe as below:

```
>>> df_list
[   A
0  1
1  2
2  3,    B
0  4
1  5
2  6,    C
0  7
1  8
2  9]
```

I would like to merge them to become a single dataframe `dat` as below:

```
>>> dat
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

One way I can get it done is to create a blank dataframe and concatenate each of them using `for` loop.

```
dat = pd.DataFrame([])
for i in range(0, len(df_list)):
        dat = pd.concat([dat, df_list[i]], axis = 1)
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this without using iteration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `list of DataFrame`s:

```
dat = pd.concat(df_list, axis = 1)
```